# VSC Debug: 'node-debug' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

This is in a demo app's package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cd public && npm run tsc && cd .. && node ./bin/www",
    "debug": "cd public && npm run tsc && cd .. && node-debug ./bin/www",
    "tsc": "cd public && npm run tsc",
    "tsc:w": "cd public && npm run tsc:w",
    "express": "node ./bin/www",
    "express-debug": "node-debug ./bin/www",
    "postinstall": "cd public && npm install"
  },
```

question 1, it was fine when I did `npm run postinstall`, but `npm run debug` got **'node-debug' is not recognized as an internal or external command.**

question 2, how do I translate this entry into launch.json file?

`"debug": "cd public && npm run tsc && cd .. && node-debug ./bin/www"`

Comment: node-debug is done by `npm install -g node-inspector`, however I'm ended up with lots of ERR, Github says to wait for new Cordova.